# Google Analytics javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Here is a Google Analytics' code

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20366831-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

How my client side calls Google anonymous function?

Answer (score 5):

It's called because the anonymous function ends with `()`

```
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})(); // <--- The () calls the anonymous code
```

As you'll see, this code basically injects a `script` tag into the DOM, which gets run by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

That snippet already call itself.

```js
(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

what it actually does is including the **ga.js** on your page, which is similar to this:

```html
<script src="//google-analytics.com/ga.js" />
```

The rest is up to you to add event to the _gaq (google analytic queue). Then the event will automatically be processed.